Why is LeetCode Test Case failing in their validation, but the output is exactly as intended in my IDE?
I am attempting the Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters(https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/description/) problem. So it has been failing the 3rd test case where length of non repeating substring from 'pwwkew' should be 3. I created my code, which uses two pointers,
I start from first index comparing it with last index, until I get e match I increment i and move forward to 2nd index, 3rd index and so on, when I do get a match I split the string there, and continue it recursively on the 2 strings, kind of like quick sort.  if my string is of length 2 and s[i]==s[j] i return 1 for test case 2.
When I ran it in VS code I got proper answers, 3,1,3 for all the cases, but the Leet Code is saying my output for 3rd case is 1. This is very confusing. How should I approach this problem.
``
Inputstr= "pwwkew"
class Solution:
    c = 50
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        
        i = 0
        j = len(s)-1
        while i<j:
            if s[i]==s[j]:
                if len(s)==2:
                    print(s)
                    Solution.c = 1
                self.lengthOfLongestSubstring(s[:i+1])
                self.lengthOfLongestSubstring(s[i+1:])
                Solution.c = min(Solution.c,len(s))
                
            i=i+1
        return Solution.c   
a= Solution()
print(a.lengthOfLongestSubstring(Inputstr))    

``
I am expecting this to return 3 in last test case, I am planning to use recursion and divide and conquer technique here instead of sliding window

Total guess: you're storing the result as a class attribute. That influences the result of subsequent tests, based on whether the code is loaded from scratch, or the already loaded class reused. Your local testing and Leetcode probably differ in that respect.

Your algorithm is badly broken. Consider what happens if an empty string is passed. Also, LeetCode is very keen on performance and a recursive solution isn't going to fit well with that paradigm

the difference in the output of leetcode and visualcode is due to the 2nd test case being run in leetcode which makes the minimum value of solution.c =1 and it stays 1.... whereas you must be running testcase 3 only in visualcode
.....
Also the logic of your code isn't clear to me and it is also not working on many other cases... for example "abcbdedf", expected 4.. your answer 50

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
